# How to copy a file from server to client system?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, client-server, html

I am creating a webpage with asp.net and C#. In which I want to do the following thing:

When a user clicks on a button from client side, a file from server locations have to be copied to a particular location of the client system and open the file. Is it possible to write C# code or javascript in service to do it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `WebClient.Download()`

Answer (score 0):

You can not tell the client browser where to store the file.

The only thing you can do is serve the file up for downloading. Where this file is placed is up to the user to choose.

Imagine if any page you browsed to could put a file anywhere it wanted on your computer.

Comment: If we use shared path for the file, is it possible to open the file in client system and view the opened file in client side screen

Comment: You can by writing the file to the response. If you chose the correct content-type and the client has a browser plugin installed (like adobe reader for pdf files) that can open the file, the file will be viewed in the browser

Comment: @middelpat - Can u please provide me the name of plugin for exe files.

Comment: A browser can't execute an exe file. Windows can, so an exe has to be downloaded. The mime type will be: "application/octet-stream"

Answer (score 0):

Only if you can control control system-wide permissions for web-applications on client's computer, so using Silverlight(or Java/Flash for example) you can write application that will download file from server and save it to specified location - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee721083(v=vs.95).aspx#file_system_access

On unknown computers standing somewhere, belonging to someone you don't know/trust, and who don't know/trust you - no, there no way.

Answer (score 0):

Like JensB stated, for security purposes a server can't put a file on a client system.
If it could, it would be very easy to spread virusses without clients even knowing they are being infected.

The only thing you can do is make the server present the file for download to the client. Therafter the client can chose wheter or not he wants to download the file and where to store it.

In asp this can be achieved bij putting something like the following in a button click handler

```
System.Web.HttpResponse response = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response;
response.ClearContent();
response.Clear();
response.ContentType = "text/plain";     //alternatively change to the content-type of your file
response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName + ";");
response.TransmitFile("Path on server to downloadable file");
response.Flush();    
response.End();
```

Comment: I have a .txt file in server side and i put it as a share to everyone. Now, is it possible to open and display that .txt file from client side.

Comment: It is not possible to ensure that from server side for security reasons. However with this code it is most likely that the browser opens the file in browser rather than prompting the user for download. But this always depends on the browser.

Comment: Alternatively you could write the contents of the file to a html element in your page so everyone could read it when they enter the page or press a button